# How is "jetty.http.idleTimeout=2000" used in jetty?

Tags: web-services, websocket, server, jetty, jetty-9

I am configuring this parameter jetty.http.idleTimeout to set the idle timeout in jetty. I would like to know how this parameter is used in jetty. I am referring to this repository below . thanks.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project

Answer (score 0):

The `jetty.http.idleTimeout` is a `jetty-start` property (not a parameter).

It can be configured in any jetty-start based Configuration Source (`${jetty.base}`, any jetty-dir, `${jetty.home}`, or command line)

It's only used by the [`http` module](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.6/jetty-server/src/main/config/modules/http.mod#L26).

And is configuring Jetty via the [`jetty-http.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.6/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-http.xml#L38) file.

You can use github search to know all of this too.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/search?p=2&q=jetty.http.idleTimeout

Comment: Thanks @Joakim I did use the github search. I was more curious about how the parameter is used in the java class after reading from the config files . How jetty honors the timeout value.

Comment: The property (not parameter) is only used by jetty-start to configure Jetty.  Nothing in the Jetty runtime looks for or uses that property at that key name.